# Footer position bottom issue

Tags: css, footer

i want that my footer is position absolute on the bottom of the page even if the content is less than window height. I've tried all possible tutorials and everything what could think of but couldn't do it.

My HTML syntax is:

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

<header>
     <div class="wrap"></div>
</header>

<div class="content wrap">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>

<footer>
    <div class="inner"></div>
</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

The site is full width i use .wrap and .inner class for width: 1000px and margin 0 auto;

If anyone could give a solution please?

Comment: you want it on bottom of window at all times, or at bottom of page if page longer than window and at bottom of window if page is shorter ?

Comment: Yeah at the bottom if page is shorter. I don't want a sticky footer which is always on top.

Comment: alright, but if page is longer, you still want it at bottom of screen, or at bottom of page?

Comment: At the bottom of the page not screen.

Comment: i believe you cannot toggle it with css alone, but its fairly easy with javascript, will you accept a javascript/jQuery solution?

Comment: Will the js/jQuery solutions be friendly for mobile etc? Responsive?

Comment: yep they definitely will. as far as im aware off, all modern mobile browsers support even html5 almost fully. shouldnt be any issue with js

Comment: Could you show me your idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a fiddle doing what you asked using jQuery: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Hj66a/1/)

basically you just compare body and window heights, if body is longer set footer to absolute,
if shorter set it to fixed:

```
$(function () {
    //change this to 'display:none'
    $('.right').css({'display':'static'});
    var footer = $('footer');
    var theDocument = $('body');
    var theWindow = $(window);
    if (theDocument.height() < theWindow.height()) {
        footer.css({
            'position': 'fixed'
        });
    } else {
        theWindow.height();
        footer.css({
            'position': 'absolute'
        });

    }
});
```

UPDATE:

here is a version that fixes the footer being over the content, you just need to move the footer down by the size of its height

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/EY5by/)

```
//######  code inside $(function () {}) will run as soon as DOM loads
$(function () {
    //change this to 'display:static' to add more content
    $('.right').css({'display':'none'});
    //sets a custom event handler to window resize + zoom, which triggers the 
    //footer fix function
    $(window).resize(function(){
        adjust_footer();
    });
    //also call this function as soon as document finishes loading
    adjust_footer();
});
//#####


function adjust_footer(){
    var footer = $('footer');
    var theDocument = $('body');
    var theWindow = $(window);
    //the  +footer.height() checks if there is enough space for footer
    //to stick it as fixed without having it cover content
    if (theDocument.height() +footer.height() < theWindow.height()) {
        footer.css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            //important, or footer will remain misplaced
            'bottom':0
        });
    } else {
        theWindow.height();
        footer.css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            //push footer down and align it to the end of content
            //meaning if footer's height is 50px, it will be pushed 50px
            //from the bottom of the content
            //* remember, bottom attribute aligns the element by its bottom
            'bottom':- footer.height()
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It's over the content still, i hate this problem it's like it has no solution lol...

Comment: lol you are right, i didnt pay attention to it, but ive fixed it now: new fiddle in the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you actually want to position the footer as a fixed element and set bottom to 0px. This will keep it at the bottom of the page no matter what.

```
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
```

Comment: It fixes it not puts on bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "fixed" property from CSS and add "bottom:0px;" so its gonna be at the bottom forever ;)

```
<header>
     <div class="wrap">Header stuff</div>
</header>

<div class="content wrap">
    <div class="left">Left Stuff</div>
    <div class="right">Right stuff</div>
</div>

<footer>
    <div class="inner">Footer stuff</div>
</footer>
```

And CSS:

```
header
{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:green;
}

.content
{
    width:100%;
    background:blue;
}

.content .left
{
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    background:blue;
}

.content .right
{
    width:70%;
    float:right;
    background:yellow;
}

.inner
{
    padding:10px;
}

footer
{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
    background:red;
}
```

Outcome is here: http://jsfiddle.net/67zR6/1/

Comment: But the footer is fixed and always displayed? I don't want the footer to be always on the bottom of the SCREEN but on the bottom of the PAGE. So if the page is shorter than content it still should stay on bottom. I think position absolute is the solution just how to use it in my case no idea, lol. I have tried everything since i really know pretty well CSS.

Comment: So yep - "absolute" position in other "relative" element will solve it.

Comment: Yeah but how? lol i've really tried everything, setting min height on body or content or using position relative for body and giving footer position absolute but it doesn't work i can't figure it out.

Comment: Ok... So lets go further: http://jsfiddle.net/nLHwE/ 
It's just using a little of jQuery. You can add a function to refresh it once window size was changed by user as well.

Comment: Yeah but what if you have a lot of content? Check http://jsfiddle.net/nLHwE/1/ the footer is on top of the content then.

Comment: You're right... So if we try how much content's you have we can end up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/nLHwE/3/

Comment: Try zooming in on fiddle you will see it still stays over content... :S